# How can you add acknowledgement functionality to a Command pattern, given the response from receiver is gotten asynchronously on Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I have a scenario where I will implement Command pattern like described in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339390/Understanding-and-Implementing-Command-Pattern-in?msg=4735932#xx4735932xx) article.

Actually from an Asp.Net MVC view, some user will invoke different commands/actions like Start Live Video, Start Live Image, Start Recording etc.
A Web Socket Server will then receive these commands and dispatch them to a Receiver (a Windows based application). The receiver before executing the requested command, will first acknowledge the received command and will confirm back to sender that the sent command has been received for processing.

Note: The acknowledgement and/or the actual response will be returned to the Web Socket Server always in an asynchronous manner and then accordingly dispatched to the sender. Means whole system is event driven based.

So my question is:

Given the Command pattern described in the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339390/Understanding-and-Implementing-Command-Pattern-in?msg=4735932#xx4735932xx), now which best way I could add Command Acknowledgement to it and will the returned acknowledgment and/or actual response be also in the form of some command/message or something else?

If we are to go something different for dispatching the Acknowledgement or response, then which pattern to use for it?

Comment: I don't think you need the Command pattern here.  I think you just need some ordinary AJAX.  MVC distinguishes its commands by having different controller methods to service those commands.  To put it another way, MVC probably already has the Command pattern, you just have to understand MVC and write a proper implementation.

Comment: You didn't understand what I asked. Acknowledgement/Response messages will also pass through the same web socket server (Command pattern based) module. In that scenario how can I fit the asynchronously received ACKs and Response messages ?. Also I am talking about handling messages on Web Socket Server and not on an Asp.Net Web Server.

Comment: That's a good question, but I still don't think the Command Pattern has anything to do with it.  It has more to do with the fact that, once your controller method executes, it won't have control anymore, so there's no way to process the received messages, unless you want to wait in the controller method for them.

Comment: All in all, I'm not sure your question is answerable.  We don't know enough details about your particular situation to make an educated guess.  The answer to your prima facie question is learn the command pattern, and figure out how it fits into your scenario.

Comment: Harvey, question is not a hard riddle set to be solved out. If you have worked on Web Sockets, you would understand what I mean. OK putting it further simpler: 
How can you add acknowledgement functionality to a Command pattern based application, given the response from receiver is gotten asynchronously on Server?

Comment: I've changed your title to the actual question you appear to be asking.  We'll see where it goes.

Comment: consider [Asynchronous Completion Token](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13132130#13132130 "discussed in more details here")

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are on the correct path way. You could **modify the command pattern** to pass a callback reference which will be used to notify the `Invoker` for the execution of the `Command`.

The abstract receiver would have an added `ExecuteAndNotify` hook method. This method would call the already existing `Execute` method on the `ConcreteCommand` and then execute the another added method called `Notify`. This `Notify` method would use the callback reference to notify the `Invoker` of the succesful execution of the command.

The callback reference could be a function pointer if the `Invoker` and the `Receiver` are classes in the same application. If they are parts of another service, it could be a URL of a "service".

Hope I helped!

Comment: Good point. "The callback reference could be a function pointer if the Invoker and the Receiver are classes in the same application. If they are parts of another service, it could be a URL of a "service"." Yes, invoker and receiver are different apps in my case, and yes your service URL looks like a good option to tackle the problem in hand. But I guess depending upon the sent command, the receiver can also respond to the appropriate method/URL on service. What if we let the receiver himself choose where to respond with result?

Comment: Nice idea. Totally oriented to your application...